# Jersey 2.13 + Bean Validation

Tags: spring, bean-validation, jersey-2.0

I'm using gradle and the following libs:

```
ext.library['jersey'] = "org.glassfish.jersey:project:2.13"
ext.library['jersey_jettison'] = "org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jettison:2.13"
ext.library['jersey_jackson'] = "org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson1:2.13"
ext.library['jersey_spring'] = "org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:2.13"
ext.library['jersey_bean_validation'] = "org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:2.13"
```

I created the bean validation structure, but its not validating at all. No error messages, nothing. This is the structure I've created:

**The DTO**

```
public class MergeSchedulesDto {

@NotNull(message = "validation.invalid.mergeFrom")
private Long mergeFrom;

@NotNull(message = "validation.invalid.mergeTo")
@NotEmpty(message = "validation.invalid.mergeTo")
private List<Long> mergeTo;
```

**The Service**

```
@Path("merge")
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response merge(@Valid MergeSchedulesDto dto, @QueryParam("units") List<Long> units) {
```

**The config**

```
public class ApplicationJAXRS extends Application {

    public ApplicationJAXRS() {
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties
                .put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages",
                        "com.sifionsolution.sig.academic.resource.service,com.sifionsolution.sig.integration.resource.filter,com.sifionsolution.sig.academic.param.converter,com.sifionsolution.sig.datatables.resource.service,com.sifionsolution.sig.datatables.converter");

        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

        singletons.add(new Jackson1Feature());
        singletons.add(new ValidationExceptionMapper());

        return singletons;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** I forgot the provider:

```
@Provider
public class ValidationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2:** I removed the JUnit test because I didnt test using Jersey Test Framework.
The problem here is that the ValidationExceptionMapper is not beeing called.

Comment: You are calling the method by yourself. What do you expect? The call needs to be made by the Jersey runtime, which intercepts the call and does the validation. In your test, the call doesn't go through Jersey. I would suggest doing an integration test with [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html) to see the validation in action. Also keep in mind that your unit should not be dependent on the validation of the bean. The  method is already under the assumption the bean is valid, so pass just pass a valid bean in the test.

Comment: Ok that made me feel stupid. I'll adjust my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Put "@Valid" in your, like this:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response insert(@Valid T obj) throws Exception{
...
}
```

This works here.